# Recursive template Angular2

Tags: javascript, recursion, angular

How can I do recursive template with Angular 2 without ng-include. I don't understand why Angular 2 won't include this skill...

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
    {{ category.title }}
    <ul ng-if="category.categories">
        <li ng-repeat="category in category.categories" ng-include="'categoryTree'">           
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-include="'categoryTree'"></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.categories = [
    { 
      title: 'Computers',
      categories: [
        {
          title: 'Laptops',
          categories: [
            {
              title: 'Ultrabooks'
            },
            {
              title: 'Macbooks'            
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: 'Desktops'
        },
        {
          title: 'Tablets',
          categories: [
            { 
              title: 'Apple'
            },
            {
              title: 'Android'
            }
          ]        
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Printers'
    }
  ];
});
```

Comment: Just create a component and do it inside that.  what's your point in doing this?

Comment: You can use component in component to do this. Use ngFor as ng-repeat and "call" component with details.

Comment: I find a solution on http://jilles.me/ng-repeat-in-angular2-ng-for/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ngFor instead of ng-repeat in Angular2.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html